# How can I convert CFAbsoluteTime to DateTime in C#?

Tags: c#, objective-c

Can anyone tell me how can I convert a value which I know to be CFAbsoluteTime from MacOS into DateTime value in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that I can convert it using following code:

```
TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(CFAbsoluteTimeFloatValue);
var cshartpDateTime = new DateTime(2001, 1, 1).Add(span);
```

Answer (score 1):

A CFAbsoluteTime is a double, the number of seconds since January 1st, 2001, 12am.  Thus:

```
    public static DateTime CFAbsoluteTimeToDateTime(double abs) {
        long ticks = (long)(abs * 1E7);  // 1 tick == 100 nsec
        return new DateTime(new DateTime(2001, 1, 1).Ticks + ticks);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. That is what I discovered little bit later, after posting the question (I spent some time searching the web before posting, and then, after posting, I was enlightened).