# How do I convert CFAbsoluteTime to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format?

Tags: c++, macos, core-foundation

How do I convert `CFAbsoluteTime` structure to `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert CFAbsoluteTime to DateTime in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058776/how-can-i-convert-cfabsolutetime-to-datetime-in-c)

Comment: @jm666 (and all) again, this is not for C# language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this piece of code (pure CoreFoundation):

```
CFAbsoluteTime cfTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
CFDateRef cfDate = CFDateCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, cfTime);
CFDateFormatterRef dateFormatter = CFDateFormatterCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFLocaleCopyCurrent(), kCFDateFormatterFullStyle, kCFDateFormatterFullStyle);
CFStringRef newString = CFDateFormatterCreateStringWithDate(kCFAllocatorDefault, dateFormatter, cfDate);
CFRelease(dateFormatter);
CFRelease(cfDate);
```

kCFDateFormatterFullStyle characterizes format. Choose one that suits you better :)